# Wrong UWP App Icons on Mobile

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[image: icon1]
[image: icon2]

I'm sending toast notifications from my UWP app which are working fine except for icon shown in the action centre. The icon appears as intended in the first image but you can see in the action centre the gray tile background is missing. I have also shown below the list of assets I have in the project.

[image: icon3]

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you set the background color of icons to be gray but Action Center is not respecting that? If so, adding the gray color to the images directly should do the work. But as a Windows user I'd prefer the bus in the icon to be white on transparent background to make it consistent with another UWP app icons.

Comment: That would be good but I have two apps for two cities and if they had the same icon (white) that would be pretty confusing for people and I'm not sure if the store even allows two apps to have the same icon.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and mark it, so other people visiting your question will see faster that this is the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to take your advice and make the tram logo white on the transparent tile background. I have discovered you can keep the StoreLogo a different png anyway so cant see there being any issue when I come to submit. Keeping the logo white and the transparent background means it works properly everywhere.